# Connectivity of sql data with java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, connectivity

This is my java code and I'm unable to connect it with MySQL.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.*;
class inPut{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id;
        char diagnosis;
        float radius_mean;
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/minor","root","MySQL");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String sql;
            System.out.println("Connected!!\n\nEnter 'n' : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            id = sc.nextInt();
            diagnosis = (char)sc.next().charAt(0);
            radius_mean = sc.nextFloat();
            sql = "insert into minor values("+id+",'"+diagnosis+","+radius_mean+");";
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println("Done stmt : "+(i+1)+"\n");
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Unable to connect");
        }
    }
}
```

Error it is showing :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.stackTraceToString(Util.java:350)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:115)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:666)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:278)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
at inPut.main(inPut.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underlying exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_US
at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:60)
... 7 more
```

And I'm unable to open jar file as well!!

Comment: how are you trying to open jar file ?

Comment: already installed but still its not working

Comment: what do you mean by install ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(""jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/minor","root","MySQL");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
```

Comment: ' inPut.java:11: error: ')' expected Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(""jdbc:mysql://localhost:330‌​6/minor","root","MyS‌​QL"); ^ inPut.java:12: error: variable declaration not allowed here Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); ^ 2 errors '  @binodpant